# Relaunching Activity again?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities  A->B->C.when i am in B activity i click the home button and put the application to back ground(B->home).

When clicking on the my application icon in the home screen the Activity A is opened not activity B .but upon long pressing the home key,its showing that my app is running in background and clicking the icon open the Activity B as expected.

What was the problem?i didn't handle any home key event.How to prevent relaunching my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a long press the dialog shows recently used app and not the ones ruuning at the moment. To make sure your activity is not killed go toSettings-> Applications-> Manage Applications -> Running tab.

Usually the behavior you described is cause by  launchMode attribute in the manifest.
Check that you do not have anything there.
read more about "launchMode" attribute [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode).